# How do I get the proxy settings of an android/ios device using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build an app using flutter and I would like to know how to retrieve the proxy settings of the device through flutter.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably safe to assume that the HttpClient doesn't pick this up automatically, but you might want to test that.

So, now you need to interact with native code using [plugins](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/). There is already a rich [library](https://github.com/flutter/plugins) of plugins providing everything from battery level to video player. I can't see proxy in there anywhere, so you need to write your own plugin (which is just one of the standard flutter project types: app, package (just Dart code allowed) and plugin). A plugin is a bit like a package (other projects can depend on it) but includes native code too. It also includes a mini-app so that you can test your plugin code while developing it.

Your plugin will end up being similar to the existing Connectivity plugin, so you may want to copy from there. In your Android method implementation you will replace

`NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();`

with

`ProxyInfo defaultProxy = manager.getDefaultProxy();`

You have return two values, the host name and the port, so put these in a Map

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("host", defaultProxy.getHost());
map.put("port", Integer.toString(defaultProxy.getPort()));
result.success(map);
```

Bonus points if you submit your changes to the Connectivity plugin.